# parse error in the final guard (incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

Tags: haskell

I get this error on the following code, but when I comment out the last line, the error goes away. What's wrong with the last or penultimate lines?

```
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

.

```
-- | Recursively builds the selector
constructSelector :: String -> Selector -> Maybe [String] -> Maybe [String] -> Selector
constructSelector docType selector inputWords tagsSoFar =
    case docType of
        "tag" -> []
        "todo" -> case inputWords of
                    Nothing -> selector
                    -- when there are no args left to examine, check if we've
                    -- recursively accumulated a list of tags
                    Just ws | ws == [] -> case tagsSoFar of
                                            Nothing -> selector
                                            Just tags -> merge selector [(pack "tags") =: tags]
                            | (head (head ws)) == 'p' && isInteger (tail (head ws)) -> constructSelector docType (merge selector [(pack "priority") =: (read $ (tail (head ws)) :: Int32)]) (remaining ws) tagsSoFar
                            | otherwise (constructSelector docType selector (Just (tail ws)) (Just (head ws):tagsSoFar))
```

Comment: On another note, I am not sure if using `Maybe` with list is beneficial as list itself can describe the 2 situations of `Nothing` (using empty list) and `Just` (using non-empty list).

Comment: oh my goodness that line is literally five thousand characters long

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed the final `->` It should be

```
| otherwise -> ...
```

On an aside, a huge nested conditional is a bit unreadable. It is worth considering refactoring the various branches into appropriately named functions to make it a bit more readable. Similarly, switching on a string and crashing at runtime if the `docType` isn't `"todo"` or `"tag"` is also a bit fishy. It might be worth doing something as trivial as

```
data DocType = Todo | Tag
```

I've found making these little type safe refactoring early on saves me tons of debugging time later on.

Comment: Upvoted just for the suggestion of making a new data declaration.